# Inhibit Time in Tx-PDO

Tags: canopen

Objects 180Nh have the following subindices:

0x00:----

0x01:----

0x02:----

0x03 (inhibit time): This subindex contains a time lock in 100 µs steps (see following figure). This can be used to set a time that must elapse after the sending of a PDO before the PDO is sent another time. This time only applies for asynchronous PDOs. This is intended to prevent PDOs from being sent continuously if the mapped object constantly changes.

0x04 (compatibility entry): This subindex has no function and exists only for compatibility reasons.

0x05 (event timer): This time (in ms) can be used to trigger an Event which handles the copying of the data and the sending of the PDO.

[image]

According to the above point, we realize that when the event occurs, a certain time is determined, which is blocked, and it is for Tx-PDO; now, if the event occurs in this interval, it will be executed in the next section.

Why should the whole section be implemented? Why is the second, third, and fourth event executed in the last part?

Shouldn't the third and fourth events be executed separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, common CANopen device profiles like for example CiA 401 "generic I/O module" are configured to suit large automation networks. That is: a large network with lots of nodes where it is important to keep bus traffic low. On such networks nodes only transmit PDOs when there has been a data update (an internal event has occurred).

However, such a setup is very much unsuitable when CANopen is used for real-time control systems, like for example having a PLC controlling a bunch of actuator I/O modules that control motions of a machine. Which could also be a safety-related application. In such systems, it is custom to always send data repeatedly at even intervals, even if it has not changed. For example send all data once every 10ms/100ms.

Only the last data sent is used by the receiving node(s), so in case data goes missing/corrupt, new reliable data will arrive soon again. And if no data arrives at all, that's an indication that something is broken and the system ought to revert to a safe state, after receiving no new data in a certain time period. This is how mobile/automotive control systems are most commonly designed, since it is safe, deterministic and proven in use. Custom, non-standard CAN bus protocols by OEM are often implemented exactly like this.

Now, to achieve this with CANopen, we have to configure the TPDO communication parameters. Event timer to set the interval and inhibit time to prevent the node spamming extra data as soon as something has changed. If I remember correctly we also need to set 180N:2 transmission type to *asynchronous* (which sounds counter-intuitive).

With a setup like this, only the most recent event matters. The most up to date data will always get sent, at fixed intervals.